# Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' when running java -jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a Spring Boot application which works fine on IntelliJ but when I try to build artifact and try to run the JAR-file, I get this error:

```
projekt-backend-1   | 16:06:15.945 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
projekt-backend-1   | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
projekt-backend-1   |   at com.hdmstuttgart.mi.backend.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:23)
projekt-backend-1   | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
projekt-backend-1   |   ... 18 common frames omitted
projekt-backend-1   | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:591)
projekt-backend-1   |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
projekt-backend-1   |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
projekt-backend-1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
projekt-backend-1   |   ... 19 common frames omitted
projekt-backend-1 exited with code 1
```

I'm trying to dockerize my Spring Boot application and I have no idea what else I can check or do.

Here is my ApplicationConfig

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hdmstuttgart.mi.backend")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

        mailSender.setUsername("${mailCredentials.username");
        mailSender.setPassword("${mailCredentials.password");

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public MJMLClient mjmlClient() {
        String appId = "${mjmlSecrets.appId}";
        String mailUsername = "${mailCredentials.username";
        return MJMLClient.newDefaultClient()
                .withApplicationID(appId)
                .withApplicationKey(mailUsername);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                /*.allowCredentials(true)*/
                .maxAge(3600L);
    }
}
```

And Main

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
public class BackendApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BackendApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
        log.debug("Backend application started");
    }

}
```

`application.yml`

```
.env:
  prefix: ""

mailCredentials:
  username: ${MAIL_USERNAME}
  password: ${MAIL_PASSWORD}

mjmlSecrets:
  appId: ${MJML_APP_ID}
  appKey: ${MJML_APP_KEY}

spring:

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openbarber
    username: postgres
    password: admin

  jpa:
    show-sql: true  # Log each SQL query
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update  # DDL auto (schema change strategy)
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: ${MAIL_USERNAME}
    password: ${MAIL_PASSWORD}
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
            required: true

#  hateoas:
#    use-hal-as-default-json-media-type: false
```

Any ideas?
Am I missing any Annotions or something?

My Dockerfile for this app

```
FROM openjdk:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B

RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

COPY target/Backend.jar .

CMD ["java", "-jar", "Backend.jar"]
```

Comment: does the application run in localhost (i.e. not in Docker container) ?

Comment: Yeah, when I start this application through IntelliJ, it works fine on localhost:8080. The error appears when I am building the jar file (need that for the Docker container). I could build the artifact but not run the jar file because of the mentioned error above

Comment: what about outside of intellij (which might provide a servlet context) but from the command line (like you are instructing Docker container to do)?

Comment: yep it did start when I ran the application from cmd with `mvn spring-boot:run` 

`2023-03-11 17:35:41.264  INFO 28012 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`
`2023-03-11 17:35:41.879  INFO 28012 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.mi.backend.BackendApplication        : Started BackendApplication in 4.651 seconds (JVM running for 4.944)`

Comment: but that's not the same command you are using in the docker container, is it?.  I am trying to see if the JAR file, when executed from command line in localhost behaves the same way as the docker container.  It could be a case of the JAR file (artifact) not having the necessary dependencies within it but expecting to find the servlet context outside of it (i.e. provided)

Comment: The JAR file when executed from the command line is not working, yes. Same error when I try to dockerize it. I edited my post and added the DOCKERFILE also

Comment: then the issue is with your artifact (i.e. the jar file) and not a docker, related thing

Comment: Have you tried starting the application locally with the jar file?  Chances are, that jar isn't the correct one.  Try running it with `java -jar target/Backend.jar`